# When can we use a function $f(\varepsilon)$ instead of simply $\varepsilon$ in proving that a sequence converges?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

When using the $\varepsilon - N$ definition of the limit of a sequence $(x_n)_n$ to prove that the sequence converges, it's common to start with values which are constante multiples of $\varepsilon$  (e.g., [$\frac{\varepsilon }{2}$ in the usual proof that the sum of two convergent sequences converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214225/my-proof-that-sum-of-convergent-sequences-converges-to-sum-of-limits)), or just some other function $f(\varepsilon)$, and go through the algebra so that in the end they cancel out to the usual inequality with just an $\varepsilon$:

$$|x_n - a| < \varepsilon$$

In the case of constant multiples, I know that finishing the proof with something like

$$|x_n - a| < k \varepsilon$$

is already enough, and one can show that both "definitions" of convergence (with $\varepsilon$ or with $k \varepsilon$) are equivalent.

**My question is**: how can we generalize that to a wider range of functions $f(\varepsilon$)? That is, when is it enough to show that, given an $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$$|x_n - a| < f(\varepsilon) \: \: \forall n \geq N$$

to prove that a sequence converges? I know, for example, that [it works for $f(\varepsilon) = \varepsilon^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152578/does-varepsilon2-instead-of-varepsilon-imply-convergence).

My intuition says $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} f(\varepsilon) = 0$ must be necessary. Is it sufficient? I also thought that the invertibility of $f$ might be involved in some way (I'm thinking of being able to "recover" $\varepsilon$ from $f(\varepsilon)$).

Comment: I agree with what you said. It's also sufficient because you can define $\epsilon' = f(\epsilon)$ and take $\epsilon$ small enough so that the thing you want to bound is smaller than the given $\epsilon'$.

Comment: Or perhaps recover something less than $\varepsilon$ from $f(\varepsilon)$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are thinking specifically is about the truth of the following:

> Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers (or complex). Also suppose that for some function $f:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb(0, \infty)$ and for some $L$, it holds good that given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $|a_n-L| < f(\epsilon)$, then the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $L$
> if and only if $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} f(\epsilon) = 0$.

But the above statement is not true. Only one way will be true. We cannot say that if the sequence converges, then $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+} f(\epsilon)$ must be $0$. A simple example to think of is to define $f(\epsilon) = 1$ for all $\epsilon>0$ considering the sequence $\{a_n\} = \{\frac{1}{n}\}$. Clearly $\{a_n\}$ converges to $0$ and for all $\epsilon$, taken $n\geq 1$, we would have
$$|a_n-0| < f(\epsilon).$$
However, $f(\epsilon)$ doesn't converge to $0$. Hence, it is not necessary that $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(\epsilon)=0$, whenever the sequence converges.

However, $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(\epsilon) $ is sufficient to conclude that $\{a_n\}$ converges. This is simple to observe. Choose $\epsilon >0$. Then, there exists $x$ such that $f(x) < \epsilon$. Now for that $x$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we would have
$$|a_n-L| < f(x) < \epsilon, $$
concluding that the sequence converges to $L$.

However, one might have noticed by now that, the condition $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(\epsilon) = 0$ is  high, in the sense, it was enough for us to have one sequence $f(x_n)$ converging to $0$ and satisfying the condition that for each $n$, there exists $N_n$ such that for all $m\geq N_n$, we would have
$$|a_m-L| < f(x_n).$$

Comment: I don't understand your first statement, you say that the sequence converges if and only if $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}f(\varepsilon) = 0$, but then you proceed to give a counterexample where the sequence converges but $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}f(\varepsilon) \neq 0$?

Comment: That statement was to reinterpret what the poser was looking for. I thought the poser was interested in knowing the truth or falsity of the first statement. I then proceeded with discussion on the falsity of that statement.